# Decomposing the output of tail

Tags: text-processing, tail

I have a text file like below. I was wondering how I can check the values of each element in the last line after using tail -n 1.

```
abd we 12345 1000
abd we 12350 1000
abd we 12355 1000
abd we 12360 1000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "check"?

Comment: I mean to compare it with a reference value like 13000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are very vague. Do you want this?

```
fields=( $(tail -n 1 file) )
if [[ ${fields[2]} == 13000 ]]; then ...
```